# Is there a nice algorithm for testing the equality of two nested radicals?

Tags: nested-radicals, symbolic-computation

I'm talking about a computer algorithm in the realm of symbolic computation. I also need to be able to write the code myself as opposed to using a third-party tool.

One way I thought of was to find any polynomials $A(x)$ and $B(x)$ of which nested radicals $\alpha$ and $\beta$, respectively, are roots. This is easier than finding minimal polynomials, I assume.

Find their GCD $G(x)$ and make sure it isn't $1$.

Then $\frac{G(x)}{x-\alpha} = \frac{G(x)}{x-\beta} \implies \alpha = \beta$.

This is right, right?

The expressions can get huge if this is done naively. Is there a neater way?

Comment: Why not a simple `\[alpha] == \[beta]` in *Mathematica*, which will give a `True` or `False`?

Comment: That's not exactly an "algorithm", @David, although it's a pretty useful technique.

Comment: It's part of some software I'm writing. I can't necessarily rely on someone else's code. I've also edited the question for clarity.

Comment: There's a bit of literature on "denesting radicals". (I don't know this, but ...) Perhaps there's a way to wrangle nested radicals into a "canonical form" that would make them straightforward to compare.